# replaceItemAtURL won't work if I tried to replace item to a different volume

Tags: cocoa, file, move, nsfilemanager

In my cocoa app I have a feature to move file to certain destination. Let's say user has a file /Users/Josh/Desktop/my.zip. User can move this my.zip file to another destination, and my.zip will be gone in Desktop.

In my code I used replaceItemAtURL, because the destination folder may also contain another my.zip:

```
bMoveSuccess = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:destinationURL withItemAtURL:sourceURL backupItemName:nil options:0 resultingItemURL:&destinationURL error:&error];
```

If I call this to move file within the same volume, it works, however if I call this and set the destination to a different volume (ie. a USB key), then I'll got the error msg saying:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “my.zip” couldn’t be saved."
UserInfo=0x101b51840 {NSFileOriginalItemLocationKey=file://localhost/Volumes/USB/my.zip,
NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/USB/my.zip, 
NSFileNewItemLocationKey=file://localhost/Users/Josh/Desktop/my.zip,
NSUnderlyingError=0x101b2e3d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Cross-device link"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work. These methods rely on the newer NSURL bookmark functionality, which can track a file's location even as it's moved while open **within the same volume**. It will not work for cross-volume moves. You'll have to change your approach (add some additional code to check for this error and handle the case specifically).

Comment: so for cross-volume moves, should I do: 1. use createFileAtPath (which allows overwrite) to replace the /Volumes/USB/my.zip with /Users/Josh/Desktop/my.zip 2. after it's done, use removeItemAtPath to remove the original one from my.zip. Is this a good approach for cross-volume moves? Also I have a question regarding sandboxing. Will I be able to do such approach, if later on I want to sandbox my app? Please advise.

Comment: I *believe* as long as you use system dialogs to let the user select a path, you're safe but I'd like someone else to chime in because I'm not absolutely certain. Regarding what you mentioned about simply overwriting an existing file, please consider asking the user (maybe just once with a "don't tell me again" option) before blasting away an existing file. You may very well have a good reason why this is alright in your case but it may very well cause someone a very bad day. Overall, though, yes, with plenty of error checking along the way, this seems to be a valid approach to me.

Comment: Also, adding a minor detail: NSURL's bookmark functionality won't work with networked volumes either.